# Using TypeScript with Vue2 and having setter on computed property causes methods to crash

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vetur, vue-typescript

I am using Vue 2.7.14 and have a problem, when trying to migrate from JS to TS. When using setters for my computed properties, I get an error from Vetur, in all my methods calling a property from the data function:

```
Property '<property>' does not exist on type 'Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, (event: string, ...args: any[]) => Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, ...>>'.Vetur(2339)
```

Event though the property 100% sure exists.

This error is triggered on my pc but not on my colleagues'.

Example of what can cause the error:

```
<script lang="ts">
export default {
data() {
  return {
    test: 'hello world'
  }
},
computed: {
  testing: {
    get() {
      return this.test;
    },
    set(value) {
      console.log(value);
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  testMethod() {
    // Test gets a red underline here and gets said error
    this.test = 'hello Mom'
  }
}
</script>
```

My gut is telling me this problem probably has something to do with Vetur parsing TS, but how to solve?

After further investigation this seems to be a problem with TypeScript and Vue2. When adding lang to `ts` on the script tag, it will throw an error everywhere a method is calling a data property.

Comment: If you have an error in IDE but not on build, the problem is specific to IDE. You can start with updating VSC and the plugin and checking the versions that the colleagues have

Comment: @EstusFlask Downgradig versions to what others have, is not helping unfortunately...